# Вывод соседних записей wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как вывести соседние записи? Нужно вывести две записи у которых id больше и 2 у которых меньше...или по дате можно...главное не рандомно! Вывожу пока так...но так выводятся последние четыре...

```
    $id_post = $post->ID;
        $args = array(
            'cat' => $cat,
            'post__not_in' => array($id_post),
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
        $relpost = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция для вывода [следующего](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) или [предыдущего](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) поста.